# Axle to wheel bore ratio?

Tags: tire, wheels, hub, axle

This may be the wrong site but it's the closest one I thought someone would have knowledge of the question...

It's not for a bike but rather replacing the wheels on a power wheels... The axle is 7/16" can I use a wheel with 5/8" axle hole (bore?) or does it have to be tighter fit like 1/2"? Or even 7/16, 15/32?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Power Wheels toy vehicles, not bicycles.

Comment: @Batman You saved me asking what on *earth* such a thing could be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an axle much smaller than the hole it fits into is sure to end badly.  However, you can make up the difference with a sleeve bushing.  Maybe you can find a standard size bushing that fits well, or maybe you'll need to invent one e.g. from copper plumbing pipe.  If you want to try the pipe approach, use 3/8" copper surrounded by 1/2" copper and you might just find a good enough fit.

You don't want the wheels to wobble...if they do, they will wear out rather quickly, and the vehicle's--ahem--performance may be adversely affected.

Comment: Yeah, you want the fit to be as close as possible without being tight.  Sometimes you can use a bushing of copper pipe, sometimes you can find a suitable bushing in a hardware store.